# How to validate Domain Classes correctly when Properties are HTML Encoded in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I use html encoding for my form input fields. I have a form to create a new user object, where one can insert a name for the new user. To prevent this input field from script injection I do **encodeAsHTML()** in the save() action listed below.

The problem: 
1. the entered name is: Schäfchen
2. this would be validated correctly after my validation rules below
3. html encoding transform ä into \auml which will fail the validation

How can I achieve that the name which in html encoded will be correctly validated?

Given the following Grails class:

```
class User {
  String name
  static constraints = {
    name blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->                     
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9äöüßÄÖÜ\\- ]+")
        pattern.matcher(val).matches()
    }
  }
}
```

in my UserController.groovy:

```
dev save() {
  def name = params?.name?.encodeAsHTML()
  def user = new User()
  user.name = name
  user.save()
}
```

Comment: Why are you encoding the data as html in the domain? You can always/should encode it as html when displaying on the page.

Comment: can you give some sample code for that? When do I use encodeAsHTML() and when do I use decodeHTML() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use encodeAsHTML() only in your GSP views.

See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html

```
<tbody>
 <g:each status="i" in="${itemList}" var="item">
  <!-- Alternate CSS classes for the rows. -->
  <tr class="${ (i % 2) == 0 ? 'a' : 'b'}">
   <td>${item.id?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
   <td>${item.parentId?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
   <td>${item.type?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
   <td>${item.status?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
 </tr>
 </g:each>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Instead of doing this over and over you can set html to be the default encoding. `grails.views.default.codec = "html"`

Comment: With your solution you will get problems with some plugins.